# Merged collections not merged. All the records in the first so first regardless of create_at date

Tags: laravel

Merged collections not merged. All the records in the first so first regardless of create_at date.
All donations appear first and then payments appear second. They are not organized based on created_date as one collection.

```
$donations = Donation::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    foreach($donations as $donation){
        $donation->type = 'Donation';
    }

    $coupayments = Payment::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    foreach($payments as $payment){
        $payment->type = 'Payment';
    }

    $payments = $donations->merge($coupayments);
```

Comment: I suppose you want to concat before ordering? See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Sort after merged two collection,

```
$donations = Donation::where('status', 1)->get();

foreach($donations as $donation){
    $donation->type = 'Donation';
}

$coupayments = Payment::where('status', 1)->get();

foreach($coupayments as $payment){
    $payment->type = 'Payment';
}

$coupayments = $donations->merge($coupayments);
$payments = $coupayments->sortByDesc('created_at');
```